# Solution Check for a Related Rates Problem Involving Shadow Length and Position

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, triangles

I am working on the following problem:

> A girl 5 ft tall is running at the rate of 12 ft/s and passes under a
> street light 20 ft above the ground. Find how rapidly the tip of her
> shadow is moving when she is (a) 20 ft past the street light, and (b)
> 50 ft past the street light.

And the follow up:

> Find how rapidly the length of the girl's shadow is increasing at each
> of the stated moments.

[image]

$ACE$ and $DEF$ are similar triangles.

Let $s=AF$ and $x=EF$. Then

$$\frac{{s+x}}{{20}}=\frac{{x}}{{5}}$$

then

$$s + x = 4x$$

then

$$s = 3x$$

Let's differentiate both sides:

$$\frac{{ds}}{{dt}} = 3\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$$

Since $$\frac{{ds}}{{dt}} = 12$$, then $$\frac{{dx}}{{dt}} = 4$$

This answers the follow-up question. So, regardless of the girl's position, the length of her shadow is increasing at a constant rate of $4$ ft/sec.

Now, to answer the original problem we need to find: $$\frac{{d(s+x)}}{{dt}}
$$

So,

$$\frac{{d(s+x)}}{{dt}}=4\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$$

Since $$\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}=4$$, then

$$\frac{{d(s+x)}}{{dt}}=16$$

So, the tip of the girl's shadow is moving at a constant rate of $16$ ft/sec, regardless of her position.

Please, verify my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your notations, we know the running velocity of the girl: $\frac{ds}{dt}=12$. We want to find:

> (1) The velocity of the shadow, namely, $\frac{dAE}{dt}=~?$

> (2) The changing rate for the length of the shadown, namely, $\frac{dx}{dt}=~?$

**Solution:**

Since $\triangle CBD\sim\triangle CAE$, we have

$$\frac{CB}{CA}=\frac{BD}{AE}\Longrightarrow \frac{15}{20}=\frac{s}{AE}\Longrightarrow AE=\frac43s$$

hence, for part (1), we get

$$\frac{dAE}{dt}=\frac43\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac43\cdot12=16$$

Next, for part (2), since $x=AE-s$, we get

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dAE}{dt}-\frac{ds}{dt}=16-12=4$$